# visual studio 2008 pasting text freeze IDE

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, copy-paste

has anyone else experienced this .  I have SP1 but i have to kill and restart VS2008 10 times a day due to this copy / paste problem.

any suggestions?

Comment: Can you give us some more information. - What type of text are you pasting (text, html, etc ...)
- How big is it?
- What language are you pasting it into?
- Are you pasting it into a designer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We experienced a similar problem. Every time someone copied and pasted anything VS2008 freeze for about 15 seconds.

After some testing we discovered this freezing was caused by the antivirus. We solved the problem adding the directories containing code to the "Excluded" list of folders for the antivirus.

***Edited:*** 
How to configure McAfee ([English Screen Shot](http://img194.imageshack.us/img194/7076/tempm.png))
[http://lh3.ggpht.com/_7ON9I_WO6GU/SkpDVOvcDMI/AAAAAAAABDI/XYUkXgur06A/s800/mcAfeeConfig.png](http://picasaweb.google.es/lh/photo/jaSbuWgkBLGr3yw6q7DsGw?authkey=Gv1sRgCL3gg5eO_b-BHw&feat=embedwebsite)

Comment: do you know how to do this with McCafee?

Comment: With McAfee 8.5 on the properties for the realtime scan you have to go to "All processes" and to the tab "Detection" the last section of the tab allows you to add directories that will be excluded on realtime analysis